# Setting Visibility Rules in Drupal Views respective to particular users

Tags: php, drupal, permissions, drupal-views

I'm setting up an administrative panel page in Durpal that pulls three views. The view that will be displayed depends on the logged in administrator, thus each of the three administrators will only see the view applicable to them.  I've added the following visibility rule to all three views (with the respective uid's).

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid == 8090){
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

It works. Now, I want to change this so that the associates of the administrators can also see it. I tried this:

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid == 8090 || 4090){
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

The associates can now see it properly, however, now the administrators are seeing other views in addition to theirs, and we don't want this to be the case. I'm a beginner to php, this is the first time I've tried it. help?

I don't know if my description above was clear enough. Basically I want this:

View 1: Visible to Administrator A
View 2: Visible to Administrator B
View 3: Visible to Administrator C

to become this:

View 1: Visible to Administrator A and Associate A
View 2: Visible to Administrator B and Associate B
View 3: Visible to Administrator C and Associate C

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create three separate admin roles and use this code to check conditions to print views

global $user;
if (in_array("Admin1", array_values($user->roles))) 
{ 

$view = views_get_view('VIEWNAME');
if ($view->access('default')) {
  print $view->preview('default');
}

}
else if (in_array("Admin2", array_values($user->roles)))
{

$view = views_get_view('VIEWNAME');
if ($view->access('default')) {
  print $view->preview('default');
}

}
else
{

$view = views_get_view('VIEWNAME');
if ($view->access('default')) {
  print $view->preview('default');
}

}

paste this code in page.tpl.php(or use it in related page) and set Access to each views.

I hope at least you get idea from this.